# Thoughts about UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios

For my new app I'm planning to use UINavigationController to push/pop other controllers.

Here is the scenario.

Application is running. Via navigation controller I push first controller on the stack. The user make some selections and touch a button. Then navigation controller push the second controller and so on while the user reach the last controller which is sixth. Controllers from first until fifth will never be used again in the app.

Is this the correct approach (using navigation controller) for such kind of app ?

Comment: Can you add more details to your question? What do you mean by 'the controllers never being used again'? Is it a one-time configuration thing? Or some sort of an "initial preferences" thing? Or is it a selection of values made every time the app is run (but the user never goes back once he reaches the sixth controller) ?

Comment: I mean that the user will never goes back once he reach the sixth controller.

Comment: Can they go back before they reach the sixth controller? Like: "One > Two > Three > Back to Two > Three" ?

Comment: Am I right in assuming this is some sort of first-run introduction to the app? Filling in details etc.

Comment: @Ell Neal, please see my comment on Alex Wayne answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure what you mean, but I guess you need to walk the user through step 1 to 5, then when they done at 6, they cannot go back. Is that correct?

I did something similar. What I did was pop up view 1-6 modally(and navigate from 1 to 6) to interrupt from the current flow, and once the user's done, the value got passed back to the view where you populate the modal view from(delegation) and then you do whatever next.

Not sure if i answered your question. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If once they reach the 6th viewController they will never go back to the other viewControllers you can always pop to the rootViewController and then push the 6th viewController on. That way those other viewControllers are not in the navigationController stack.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a flow of 5 linked screens, and then the rest of your app.

If so, yes, `UINavigationController` would work fine here.  You would push those 5 screens, and when its done you would destroy the navigation controller and replace it with some view for the rest of your app.

So the `UINavigationController` would control one part of your app, but not your *entire* app.

Comment: Actually, the fifth controller collects all data from previous controllers. There is a button in the fifth controller which push the sixth view.
If the user shake the device in the sixth view the fifth should be loaded again. Then the user can change some values and again the sixth view is loaded and so on.